# MySql Trigger - String Comparison in IF Statment

Tags: mysql

I'm running mysql 5.0 and have created a trigger. Roughly as follows:

```
SET @temp =(SELECT STATEMENT);

IF(@temp = 'true') THEN 
  -code block 1-
ELSE
  -code block 2-
END IF;
```

When I run my select statement alone it returns 'true' however in the code above 'code block 2' is being executed. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you include the select statement? Does it return only a single row and the STRING 'true' in lower case?

Comment: It returns one row with true in lower case

    +------------------+
    | temp             |
    +------------------+
    | true             |
    +------------------+

Comment: Maybe you've run into charset issues. The charset in the trigger is UTF8 (IIRC), if the charset in the table is incompatible the IF will not match.

Answer (score 0):

If your select statement is returning a boolean value then this should work:

```
SET @temp =(SELECT STATEMENT);

IF(@temp = true) THEN 
  -code block 1-
ELSE
  -code block 2-
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @temp contains way more than 'true'.  Without any additional information, this seems it should be re-written so you aren't searching through strings.  However, this may be what you are looking for (if 'true' is in the return string):

```
IF (INSTR(@temp, 'true') > 0) THEN
   -code block 1-
ELSE
   -code block 2-
END IF
```